# LDA in python using sklearn

Tags: python, algorithm, lda

I am trying to implement the LDA algorithm using the sklearn, in python

The code is:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.lda import LDA



X = np.array ([[0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.001550, 
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.201550, 0.011111, 0.077778,
                0.011111, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.092732, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.035659, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.066667, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.010853,
                0.000000, 0.033333, 0.055556, 0.055556, 0.077778, 
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.268170, 0.000000, 
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.130233, 0.000000, 
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.034109, 0.077778, 0.055556, 0.011111, 
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.155388, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.181395, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.001550, 0.007752, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.011111, 0.088889, 0.033333,
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.142857, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.093023, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.009302, 0.010853, 
                0.000000, 0.100000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.022222, 0.088889, 0.033333, 0.238095,
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.032558,
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.182946, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.022222, 0.077778, 0.055556,
                0.000000, 0.102757],
                [0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.001550, 
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.201550, 0.011111, 0.077778,
                0.011111, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.092732, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.035659, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.066667, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.010853,
                0.000000, 0.033333, 0.055556, 0.055556, 0.077778, 
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.268170, 0.000000, 
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.130233, 0.000000, 
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.034109, 0.077778, 0.055556, 0.011111, 
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.155388, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.181395, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.001550, 0.007752, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.011111, 0.088889, 0.033333,
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.142857, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.093023, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.009302, 0.010853, 
                0.000000, 0.100000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.022222, 0.088889, 0.033333, 0.238095,
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.032558,
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.182946, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.022222, 0.077778, 0.055556,
                0.000000, 0.102757]])

y = np.array ([[0.000000, 0.000000, 0.008821, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.179631, 0.010471, 0.036649,
                0.026178, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.020942, 0.010471,
                0.000000, 0.109215, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.060144, 
                0.000000, 0.042502, 0.000000, 0.005613, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.018444, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.013633,
                0.020942, 0.031414, 0.083770, 0.015707, 0.041885,
                0.041885, 0.057592, 0.010471, 0.233788, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.018444, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.090617, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.104250, 0.005236, 0.020942, 0.031414,
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.010471, 0.015707, 0.005236,
                0.056314, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.026464, 0.000000,
                0.004010, 0.000000, 0.031275, 0.007217, 0.036889,
                0.007217, 0.013633, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.005236,
                0.047120, 0.057592, 0.015707, 0.010471, 0.047120,
                0.062827, 0.005236, 0.262799, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000802, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.001604, 0.000000, 0.052927, 0.000000,
                0.039294, 0.026178, 0.041885, 0.031414, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.041885, 0.073298, 0.000000, 0.308874,
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.236568, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.020942, 0.015707,
                0.000000, 0.029010,
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.008821, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.179631, 0.010471, 0.036649,
                0.026178, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.020942, 0.010471,
                0.000000, 0.109215, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.060144, 
                0.000000, 0.042502, 0.000000, 0.005613, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.018444, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.013633,
                0.020942, 0.031414, 0.083770, 0.015707, 0.041885,
                0.041885, 0.057592, 0.010471, 0.233788, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.018444, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.090617, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.104250, 0.005236, 0.020942, 0.031414,
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.010471, 0.015707, 0.005236,
                0.056314, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.026464, 0.000000,
                0.004010, 0.000000, 0.031275, 0.007217, 0.036889,
                0.007217, 0.013633, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.005236,
                0.047120, 0.057592, 0.015707, 0.010471, 0.047120,
                0.062827, 0.005236, 0.262799, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000802, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.001604, 0.000000, 0.052927, 0.000000,
                0.039294, 0.026178, 0.041885, 0.031414, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.041885, 0.073298, 0.000000, 0.308874,
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.236568, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.020942, 0.015707,
                0.000000, 0.029010 
                ],
                [0.000000, 0.000000, 0.008821, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.179631, 0.010471, 0.036649,
                0.026178, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.020942, 0.010471,
                0.000000, 0.109215, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.060144, 
                0.000000, 0.042502, 0.000000, 0.005613, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.018444, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.013633,
                0.020942, 0.031414, 0.083770, 0.015707, 0.041885,
                0.041885, 0.057592, 0.010471, 0.233788, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.018444, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.090617, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.104250, 0.005236, 0.020942, 0.031414,
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.010471, 0.015707, 0.005236,
                0.056314, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.026464, 0.000000,
                0.004010, 0.000000, 0.031275, 0.007217, 0.036889,
                0.007217, 0.013633, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.005236,
                0.047120, 0.057592, 0.015707, 0.010471, 0.047120,
                0.062827, 0.005236, 0.262799, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000802, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.001604, 0.000000, 0.052927, 0.000000,
                0.039294, 0.026178, 0.041885, 0.031414, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.041885, 0.073298, 0.000000, 0.308874,
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.236568, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.020942, 0.015707,
                0.000000, 0.029010 ]

                ])             
clf = LDA()
clf.fit(X,y)
print(clf.predict([1, 2]))
```

But, I got the message error:

```
 clf.fit(X,y)
 fac = 1. / (n_samples - n_classes)
 ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

What I do to solve this error?

I am using this version of the LDA, from SKLEARN http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.lda.LDA.html

Thank you, very much!

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to paste all of your code to see why it's happening, but the problem is that `(n_samples - n_classes)` is equal to `0`

Comment: Hi. this is the entire code. I guess this is a bug on module LDA of the sklearn, what do you think? 

The line error on the lda.py module is
fac = 1. / (n_samples - n_classes)
thanks you!